# Combinator with an endomorphism and a predicate in scala

Tags: scala

Is there a library that defines such a useful combinator ?

```
  def f[A](g: A => A, pred: A => Boolean) : A => A = {
    a =>
      val newA = g(a)
      if (pred(newA)) newA else a
  }
```

Comment: I wonder if this is somehow useful: http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/FunctorFilter.html

Comment: I don't see how to use it in this case. Can you provide some code ?